# Look for a design pattern for managing an operation that needs to update data in multiple datasources

Tags: c#, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, solid-principles

I have an api with a post operation. We are using C# and have separate assemblies for each layer (Api, Business Logic, Data Access)

This operation has to interact with multiple datasources.

1. Check if the data already exists in datasource 1
2. If it doesn't exist in datasource 1, check if the data already exists in datasource 2
3. If it doesn't exist in datasource 2, insert it in to datasource 1 and then insert it in to datasource 2

We regularly make use of services (for logic) and repositories for data access.

**Option 1**

- Create a repository for each datasource, each with a get operation and an insert operation.
- Create a service which consumes both repositories and follows the logic above.

The advantage is that all the logic is in the service and it feels a little more "Single Responsibility". The downside to this is someone at a later date could use the "datasource 1 repository" directly and insert a record without knowing that it should be inserted in to datasource 2 as well.

**Option 2**
Create one single repository, with a single get and insert operation that interacts with both datasources. This would ensure that you cannot interact with one without the other but feels much less as "Single Responsibility".

**Option 3**
Have 3 repositories....

- 1 repository for datasource 1 (but has an internal only interface so couldn't be consumed by another assembly)
- 1 repository for datasource 2 (but has an internal only interface so couldn't be consumed by another assembly)
- 1 repository with public interface and can be consumed by the service (in a different assembly)

The public repository could consume the 2 "datasource specific" repositories and follow the logic above. This shifts the logic from the service to the repository but has the advantage that the implementation is hidden to anyone outside of the data layer.

What are peoples thoughts? Is there a design pattern for this?

Comment: Do the datasources have identical structure and schema?

Comment: `We regularly make sure of services and repositories` - I don't understand what this means, could you clarify?

Comment: Hi @CodingYoshi - the datasources are not identical.

Datasource 1 is for a brand new system. Datasource is in a legacy database and holds the key to datasource 1 plus some additional values.

Comment: @CraigBroadman You can still use my solution in my answer. Whether structure of data is the same or not.

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu that was a typo - was meant to say we regularly make use - I have updated

Comment: With the public and internal repo approach, you will have the logic in the public repo but that logic should be in a service. Having said that, I think it is no big deal and I am starting to think this is probably not a bad idea at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On one hand, I could create a repository for each datasource, each with a get operation and an insert operation. Then I could create a service which follows the logic above.
>
> The advantage is that all the logic is in the service and it feels a little more "Single Responsibility".

I like this option too so if I were you, I would go with this option.

> Another option is to create a single repository, with a single insert operation that interacts with both datasources. This would ensure that you cannot interact with one without the other but feels much less as "Single Responsibility".

I do not like this option of putting the checking of datasources in one repo because this sounds like the responsibility of the service layer.

> Another option is to have 3 repositories. 1 that is public, consumed by the service (DDD) and this repository talks to the datasource specific repositories that are internal only.

I am not sure what you mean by internal only. If by internal you mean `internal` as in within the assembly, it still has the same shortcoming as the previous option.

About first option, which I and you like, you say this:

> The downside to this is someone could easily come along at a later date and use the "datasource 1 repository" directly and insert a record without knowing that it should be inserted in to datasource 2 as well.

We can do something to avoid that. Create a class like this and imagine we are saving `Customer`:

```
public class Customer { }

public class CustomerData
{
    public string MyProperty { get; private set; }

    private CustomerData()
    {
    }

    public Customer Customer { get; private set; }

    // or not void
    public static void Save(Customer customer)
    {
        // Check all datasources and save wherever you need to 
        // obviously through injection or whatever. I will just
        // new-it up here
        var cd = new CustomerData { Customer = customer };
        var repo1 = new CustomerRepository();
        repo1.Save(cd);

        bool someCondition = true;
        if (someCondition)
        {
            var repo2 = new CustomerRepository();
            repo2.Save(cd);
        }
    }
}
```

Please note the constructor is private so devs cannot create it. Now create your repository like this:

```
public class CustomerRepository
{
    public void Save(CustomerData cd) { // Save cd.Customer to datasource }
}
```

Please note it takes `CustomerData` as argument.

OK! So let's use the repo:

```
var repo = new CustomerRepository();
// Oops cannot create CustomerData. 
// repo has no other method except for CustomerData.
repo.Save(new CustomerData()); 

// There is no other way except for this or the developer has to add 
// a method to the repo-but what can we do about that, not much!
CustomerData.Save(new Customer());
```

Comment: I have updated my post with some additional details. Whilst using a private constructor would limit a dev from creating an instance of an object, this seems quite hacky. I like to follow SOLID principles and always use dependency injection.

Comment: @CraigBroadman Please explain why it is hacky and why it is not following SOLID?

Comment: On reflection I think that option 1 is probably the best option. It doesn't seem that there is a design pattern that specifically fits this scenario. I appreciate everyone's comments

Answer (score 0):

The requirement feels a lot like the [Chain of Responsibility Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern), unfortunately that won't do a lot to reduce the amount of data access code. I'd be tempted to have a reader per 'level' in the checks, make them all implement some common interface, and use a chain of responsibility (i.e. Can I handle this, if not ask the next object in the chain) to do the operations. You could make each of the items in the chain a mini repository, or use another repository if required.

Maybe only worry about specific repositories if you already have them in the structure, or need similar readers elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for these silly drawings, but I tried to represent your workflow as a finite automata.

[image]

So, I suppose we can reduce it like this.

[image]

And have just one valid data source.

Also, consider the synchronization mechanism if you need to, which can cause an overhead.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see the interface is something like `persistSomethingToRepository`. This interface is all the the client code care about. It does not care about the fact that you use a secondary legacy system (nor it should). This observation simplifies the implementation a lot as you can use the [Decorator pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) to decorate the DataSource1 with the persisting to the DataSource2 also.

I don't have (yet) enough experience in C# but the pseudo OOP code is something like this:

```
interface Repository {
    void persistSomething(something);
}

class Source1 implements Repository {
    void persistSomething(something) {
        // insert into database
   }
}

class Source2AndSource1 implements Repository {
    // inject the right database connection and a Source1 instance
    void persistSomething(something) {
        // Check if the data already exists in datasource 1
        // If it doesn't exist in datasource 1, check if the data already exists in datasource  2
       //If it doesn't exist in datasource 2, insert it in to datasource 1 and then insert it in to datasource 2
   }
}
```

Then you just configure your Dependency injection container (DIC) to use an instance of `Source2AndSource1` when a `Repository` is needed.

When your legacy system (source 2) is not used anymore you just configure your DIC to use an instance of `Source1` instead of `Source2AndSource1`, without any modification to the client code. This gets you a [SOLID](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) code, more exactly the [Open/closed Principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) and the [Single responsibility principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).